# why self built g++ compiler fails to compile my code

Tags: c++, c, linux, gcc, c++11

I wanted to use latest g++ compiler(4.9.1) on suse linux, but suse only supports an older g++ version. So, I took a latest source code from one of the gnu mirror sites and compiled it myself. Everything went fine. But when I tried to compile my test code using the built g++, the compilation fails with error, 
"**/root/home/include/c++/4.9.1/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/bits/os_defines.h:39:22: fatal error: features.h: No such file or directory**".

I can find a "**features.h**" in "**/root/home/include/c++/4.9.1/parallel**", but I feel that it should be there in "**/root/home/include/c++/4.9.1/**" itself.

I copied "**/root/home/include/c++/4.9.1/parallel/features.h**" to "**/root/home/include/c++/4.9.1/**" just to see what happens. Now it complains with error "whcar.h" not found.

Have I missed something.

Here are the steps I followed to build g++.

```
1. /root/home/gcc_build/objdir# ../gcc-4.9.1/configure --prefix=/root/home/ --disable-multilib
2. /root/home/gcc_build/objdir# make -j16
3. /root/home/gcc_build/objdir# make install
4. /root/home/gcc_build/test#  /root/home/bin/g++ --sysroot /root/home -m64 test.cpp
```

Comment: Did you perform install to prefix or just copy the executables?

Comment: @Tanuki I don't know what OP did, but installing to prefix does _not_ solve this problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I resolved the issue by removing sysroot option and pointing c++ include and library path to my home directory. One thing I noticed was that the g++ source does not come with libc and c header files, and libc has to be installed seperately. But with sysroot option, g++ was trying to look all the header files in my home directory.

Below is the command I used to successfully compile the code.

```
/root/home/bin/g++ -I /root/home/include/c++/4.9.1 -L /root/home/lib64 -Wl,--rpath=/root/home/lib64 --std=c++0x -m64 test.cpp
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the [GCC Directory Options](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Directory-Options.html). It is important to use the correct "specifier" as well (-isystem, -L, -B, -I etc)